# GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB (billboarding) problems with lighting upon rotation

Tags: c++, c, linux, opengl

I created a small application to display individual particles:

[image: img]

When I rotate around the scene the lighting changes and the particles almost become invisible:

[image: img]

Is it possible to force setting the lighting over the entire rotation?

Relevant code:

```
// init
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glAccum(GL_RETURN, 0.95f);

glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearAccum(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);



float quadratic[3]  = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.01337f };
float linear[3]  = { 0.0, 1, 0.0 };
float constant[3]  = { 0.01, 0.0, 0.0 };

glPointParameterfvARB(GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION_ARB, quadratic);
float maxSize = 0.0f;
glGetFloatv( GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX_ARB, &maxSize );
glPointSize( maxSize );
glPointParameterfARB( GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX_ARB, maxSize );
glPointParameterfARB( GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN_ARB, 1.0f );

QImage b("particle.bmp");

QImage t;
t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(b);
glGenTextures(1, texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB, GL_COORD_REPLACE_ARB, GL_TRUE);
```

And the draw function:

```
// draw function:

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glAccum(GL_RETURN, 0.95f);
glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 0.7f);

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
// Loop over all particles and draw the gl points separately:
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 0.5f);
```

In case you want to test it yourself [here's](https://github.com/moeeeep/Donkey2/blob/master/src/viewer.cpp) the complete code.  I use libqglviewer for the camera rotation.

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen usually captures only the active window.

Comment: I know. Screenshots seemed kind of secondary to me. I updated them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off `GL_LIGHTING`.  I'm not sure why you have it on in the first place.

Comment: Hah, yes. That did it indeed! I created this post on a different computer and forgot to commit this changes. So I had code in front of me that looked like this:
'
     glEnable(GL_BLEND);
     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB);
     glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 0.7f);
     glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        draw();
     glEnd();
     glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB);
     glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     glDisable(GL_BLEND);
'
Which made me remember, that libqglviewer *might* enable GL_LIGHTING for the draw function. I only needed to disable GL_LIGHTING in the first place.